# Install Windows 10 Mobile Build 14356 on any Lumia device (1gb & Above)

Tags: insider-preview, redstone-builds, unsupported-phones

This tutorial rather a hack allows you to install latest Redstone Build 14356 on Many older Lumia devices. Many Lumia 920, 1020 and 1320 owners have been able to install the Build 14356 using the hack, though there are some minor issues as reported by those who have installed it, so do it at your own risk.

- Brightness is not working.
- Glance screen is missing.
- Battery draining so fast.

Follow the steps in the Answer section -> :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note** – Following steps may cause damage to your phone. Microsoft will not responsible for any damage. Do at your own Risk. Think Twice before trying.

**Steps:**

1. Firstly, install Windows Insider app from store.
2. Then download Registry Edior "vcReg_1.5" and deploy on it your device using app deployment tool.
3. Then go to *vcreg > … > templates*, check mark, live interop and restore Ndtksvc and click on apply.
4. Then deploy customPFD and move it to *HKLM–>SYTEM–>Platform–>DeviceTargetingInfo* then change
   a) PhoneManufacturer “=MicrosoftMDG
   b)change "PhoneManufacturerModelName “=RM-1085_113025.
5. After that open Windows insider app, the apply for builds select fast ring then your device will reboot as usual and then check for update in phone update setting. You will get it. The update size is all about 600MB.

**Links:**

- VC_reg 1.5 - http://fileshub.in/3gm
- CustomPFD - http://fileshub.in/3gn
- WP8.1 SDK Tools Lite (for app deployment(needs minimum win 8.1 on pc) - http://www13.zippyshare.com/v/15281796/file.html